# ive downloaded the latest ubuntu and copied it to a usb stick

Tags: usb

ive downloaded the latest ubuntu iso file and copied it to my usb stick. i'm trying to boot from the USB stick on an aspire one net book and its telling me that its missing the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you copied the iso

Great instructions from the link below. It explains how to make the flash drive bootable and the software (with download links) to use from various operating systems to do the job.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick